# How do I make button linked to another function in the same page?

Tags: html

I'm creating a page where the `Next` button in the page will redirect user to another tab / class in the same page.

I wanted a button that will link me to the next tab which is the `Attachment` tab using the `#note` as the reference.

What I have tried is I tried to put a link in the button but its not working. Is there any other way on how to do it? Other than put a link to it ?

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-right mt-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" title="Add"><a href="next">Next</a></button>
</div>
```

```
<div class="default-tab">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#next">Attachment</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="col-md-12 text-right mt-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" title="Add">Next</button>
  </div>


 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="next">
      <div class="pt-4">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            ......
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution, below what I have tried

first I will add `id="mytabs"` in the `ul`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="mytabs">
```

then at the button part I add on `id="next"`

```
 <div class="col-md-12 text-right mt-4">
      <button type="button" id="nextTab" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" title="Add">Next</button>
 </div>
```

and lastly the javascript

```
 <script>
      $(function(){                                                  
          $('#nextTab').click(function(e){                                                
              e.preventDefault();
              $('#mytabs a[href="#next"]').tab('show'); 
               })
             })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add "#" in href.
Like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-12 text-right mt-4">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" title="Add"><a href="#next">Next</a></button>
```

Comment: I have tried this one but it will return the url with `https://localhost/as_register/register#next`  and it not show the next page

Comment: Probably, the next div doesn't appear because of the class "fade". The div is probably hidden.

Comment: you need also to add id to the next tab/class
if the following is your tab 
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="next">Attachment</a>

Answer (score 0):

other than just adding an anchor tag, the possible way is to use javascript

HTML code :

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-right mt-4">
    <button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" title="Add">
        Next
    </button>
</div>
```

here the javascript code,

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button#next');
const target = '#next';
btn.onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + target;
}
```

Comment: I inspected the button then I got error with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`

Comment: add `id` attribute first in your button tag, `id="next"`. you can use the HTML code I presented